# Disable RFH2 headers while posting message to IBM MQ via JMS bridge

Tags: activemq-classic, ibm-mq

I am publishing message to ActiveMQ queue (TEST.AMQ.QUEUE), which is Bridged to IBM MQ queue (TEST.IBM-MQ.QUEUE) by the following configuration in activmq.xml:

```
<bean id="remoteFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">                                              
        <property name="username" value="***"></property>
        <property name="password" value="***"></property>
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
            <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
                <property name="hostName" value="1*.2*6.**.***" />
                <property name="port" value="1*1*" />
                <property name="queueManager" value="Q****HUB" />
                <property name="channel" value="Q*****D" />
                <property name="transportType" value="1" />
            </bean>
        </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configure JMS bridge -->
<jmsBridgeConnectors>
    <jmsQueueConnector outboundQueueConnectionFactory="#remoteFactory">
        <outboundQueueBridges>
            <outboundQueueBridge outboundQueueName="TEST.IBM-MQ.QUEUE" />
        </outboundQueueBridges>
    </jmsQueueConnector>
</jmsBridgeConnectors>
```

I need to set the property **TARGCLIENT** as MQ, to disable RFH2 headers, how can i provide this property in activemq.xml file, in which my bridge configurations are defined.

Answer (score 0):

The targetClient property can be set on queues, but I'm not sure where it will fit with the bridge.

Could try this name:

queue:///TEST.IBM-MQ.QUEUE?targetClient=1

Or maybe define a bean, and reference that:

```
<bean id="queue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue"
        depends-on="remoteFactory">
    <property name="baseQueueManagerName" value="*queue manager*" />
    <property name="baseQueueName" value="TEST.IBM-MQ.QUEUE" />
    <property name="targetClient" value="1" />
</bean>
```